# COM+ (.NET) application backwards compatibiliy

Tags: c#, msmq, com+

I have written a COM+ component in .NET 3.5 on a Windows 7 machine.  Unfortunately, after I had programmed everything I came to know that the server where this component should reside is a windows 2003 server.  By now most of you might have guessed what the issue could be.  If not, here it is:

The issue is that when I try and install the component on the windows 2003 machine, I get the following error:

*An unknown COM+ 1.0 catalog error occurred:
1: MSMQ is required for the requested operation and is not installed (Exception form HRESULT: 0x80110602)*

I installed the MSMQ services on the machine before the installation of the COM+ component.  After some research, I found out that Windows 7 uses MSMQ 5.0 and Windows 2003 uses MSMQ 2.0.

So, is there a way to "downgrade" my COM+ component to work with MSMQ 2.0?  How else can I get the COM+ component installed?

Comment: Did you get any error after installing MSMQ?

Comment: Nope no errors after installing MSMQ.  Only when trying to install the COM+ component.

Comment: "After some research, I found out that Windows 7 uses MSMQ 5.0 and Windows 2003 uses MSMQ 2.0." Not so - Windows 2003 is MSMQ 3.0.

Comment: After a bit of research, we discovered that it was Active Directory interfering somehow.  Not sure how, but now I have the component installed.

Comment: I assume you installed MSMQ in its entiriety without disabling any of the subcomponents. If your machine is a member of a domain then it will try and install MSMQ in Active Directory Integrated mode instead of Workgroup Mode. This can fail if the logged in user does not have enough permissions to create the necessary AD objects. This will cause problems for anything trying to create public queues. Maybe QC was trying to do that and not succeeding.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing, 0x80110602, is COMQC_E_QUEUING_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE.
That looks like a Queued Components error code. 
Queued Components was the software used to call COM+ components using the MSMQ protocol instead of the usual RPC protocol.

I think you need to describe in more detail:

1. If you installed the Queued Components part of MSMQ; this feature was rarely used by developers and I doubt you coded to use it in your component.
2. How you installed your COM+ component
3. Did you set the Queued property on the COM+ application in Component Services?
4. What the component has to do with MSMQ; if you are not using MSMQ, you don't need this installed.

I'm confident that this is just going to be a misunderstanding/configuration issue.

Cheers
John Breakwell

Comment: When I installed MSMQ, I didn't get an option to install Queued components (COM+).  If I understand correctly, COM+ components use MSMQ as a transport mechanism.

To install the COM+ component, I first placed my dll into GAC and then used the 'regsvcs /c' executable.  That creates the queue for the COM+ component.

Comment: "If I understand correctly, COM+ components use MSMQ as a transport mechanism." 
No, they CAN use MSMQ as a transport but the vast majority use the default RPC mechanism.